# Python won't run or save a specific script?

Tags: python

I've been trying to learn python so for practice I was doing this:

```
def checkFermat(a, b, c, n):
    if n>2 and a**n + b**n == c**n:
        print 'Holy smokes, Fermat was wrong!'
    else:
        print 'No, that doesn’t work'
```

For some reason python won't run or save this but it works perfectly fine for every other script, does anybody know if there is any particular reason this is happening?

Comment: what do you mean by python will not run it?

Comment: My first guess is that you forget to call your function.

Comment: What do you mean "won't save"? Are you using an IDE?

Comment: I mean that when i press F5 nothing pops up and this is after calling the function, and yes i'm using an IDE

Comment: Example input and output please... which IDE? You make it impossible to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Note: When I tried testing your code its seems that your are using a non-ASCII char in print statement which says `print 'No, that doesn’t work'` it could be the reason due to which your script it failing to run.*

This is how you can make it as a script:

1. Open your text editor.
2. Write the code in it as:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python
   def checkFermat(a, b, c, n):
       if n>2 and a**n + b**n == c**n:
           print 'Holy smokes, Fermat was wrong!'
       else:
           print 'No, that doesn\'t work'

   if __name__ == "__main__":   
       checkFermat(10,20,30,40) #sample for testing
   ```
3. Save it as a file say `myscript.py`.
4. Open your console and run it as:

   ```
   python myscript.py
   ```

Comment: It was because of the non-ASCII char haha, sorry and thank you to everyone that replied

Comment: @rezale If an answer completely answered your question, remember that you can accept it. This is completely optional but a nice way to say thanks to the person that helped you.